# Getting java.io.EOFException when calling readObject() on ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I am trying to implement simple UDP communication between two sockets. In order to be sent in UDP packet, data needs to be converted to byte array. I created simple class named Packet which is used to store various data types. This class implements Serializable interface so it can be converted to byte array and sent over UDP protocol. Program worked fine until I put HashMap object inside Packet class. Error occurs on server side when recived data is being converted back to Packet object.

Here is client code:

```
package hr.fer.tel.rassus.udp.server;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.HashMap;    

public class UDPClient {

final static int PORT = 10001; // server port


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {


    HashMap<Integer, Integer> vector = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    vector.put(1, 2);
    Packet p = new Packet(10000,10001,"co2",0,vector);
    byte[] serializedMessage = null;
    try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutput oo = new ObjectOutputStream(bStream);
            oo.writeObject(p);
            serializedMessage = bStream.toByteArray();
            oo.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error "+ex.toString());
    }

    // determine the IP address of a host, given the host's name
    InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

    // create a datagram socket and bind it to any available
    // port on the local host
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(); //SOCKET

    // create a datagram packet for sending data
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(serializedMessage, serializedMessage.length,
            address, PORT);

    // send a datagram packet from this socket
    socket.send(packet); //SENDTO
    socket.close(); //CLOSE
}
}
```

Server code:

```
package hr.fer.tel.rassus.udp.server;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;




public class UDPServer {

final static int PORT = 10001; // server port

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    byte[] rcvBuf = new byte[256]; // received bytes

    // create a UDP socket and bind it to the specified port on the local
    // host
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT); //SOCKET -> BIND

    while (true) { 
        // create a DatagramPacket for receiving packets
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(rcvBuf, rcvBuf.length);

        // receive packet
        socket.receive(packet); //RECVFROM

        // construct a new String by decoding the specified subarray of
        // bytes
        // using the platform's default charset
        ObjectInputStream iStream;
        Packet p = null;


        try {
            iStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(packet.getData()));
            p = (Packet) iStream.readObject();
            iStream.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UDPServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



    }
}
}
```

Packet class:

```
package hr.fer.tel.rassus.udp.server;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 *
 * @author adrianzgaljic
 */
public class Packet implements Serializable{



private int fromPort;
private int toPort;
private String co2;
private boolean flag;
private long timeStamp;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> vector;
Set<Integer> keys;



public Packet(int from, int to, String co2, long time, HashMap<Integer, Integer> vector){

    this.fromPort = from;
    this.toPort = to;
    this.co2= co2;
    this.timeStamp = time;
    this.vector = vector;
    flag = false;

}

public Packet(int from){
    this.fromPort = from;
    this.flag = true;
}

    public int getFromPort() {
    return fromPort;
}

public int getToPort() {
    return toPort;
}

public String getCo2() {
    return co2;
}

public long getTimeStamp() {
    return timeStamp;
}

public boolean isFlag() {
    return flag;
}

public HashMap<Integer, Integer> getVector() {
    return vector;
} 



}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2325)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3063)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2864)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1072)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:704)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:830)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1601)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
at hr.fer.tel.rassus.udp.server.UDPServer.main(UDPServer.java:48)
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 4):

After running your code I realized that my previous answer was not solving the issue, however I will leave it along with the new one, because it describes an issue that may cause similar effect.

New answer:

Your server's datagram packet size is too small to receive all the data you are sending, increase its size by increasing the buffer size:

```
byte[] rcvBuf = new byte[256]; // received bytes
```

e.g. `new byte[2048]`

Old answer:

Swap these two lines in the client:

```
serializedMessage = bStream.toByteArray();
oo.close();
```

So you should have this:

```
oo.close();
serializedMessage = bStream.toByteArray();
```

The issue with your code is that you are getting the bytes, while `ObjectOutputStream` didn't actually flush all the data to your `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but swapping those two lines didn't solve my problem, I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: In addition, although it won't change anything, strictly speaking `iStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(packet.getData()))` should be `iStream = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength()));`

Comment: Faced exactly the same issue: You are right @user3707125. It is because of the size of the byte array.To confirm it, i checked the length of the buffer after serialization and bingo it was larger than the size of the byte array  I allocated at the server.